# How to create app data directory in Tauri?

Tags: rust, desktop-application, tauri

I am building an app using Tauri framework. I read about how to access the app data folder path in [Tauri Docs](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/command#accessing-an-apphandle-in-commands)

But when I try creating a database in this folder, I get an error:

`The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)`

Also, when I check the path (`~\AppData\Roaming\com.tauri.dev` in Windows), the folder is not already present (I mean, there is **no** `com.tauri.dev` directory **in** `AppData\Roaming`), and I need to create it (possibly).

I need to create it as soon as the application is started, preferably from some setting in `tauri.conf.json` (if such setting exists). How to do it?

**Edit:**

Note that `~\AppData\Local\com.tauri.dev` is automatically created on running the app. I want the same to happen for `~\AppData\Roaming\com.tauri.dev`

Answer (score -1):

Try accessing AppData folder as stated in the [docs](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/path#appdatadir).

Example:

```
import { appDataDir } from '@tauri-apps/api/path';
const appDataDirPath = await appDataDir();
```

Then you may use this directory with `fs` or whatever you need.